# Java/eclipse não reconhece anotação Path GET

Tags: java, java-ee, jersey

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Restful, usando eclipse e jersey (Sem usar framework).

Porém to tendo um problema na anotações do tipo @Path, @GET.
Quando uso essas anotações dá um erro na linha do pacote dentro da classe.
O seguinte erro:

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referened from required .class file

E acredito que por isso todas vez que inicio o servidor/rodo a aplicação não conseguido acessar os dados. Pois toda vez q acesso a uri que deveria me retornar os dados recebo um

> "HTTP Status 404- /PrimeiroRestfl".
>
> description The requested resource is not available

Todas as lib do jersey estão adicionadas no path e estou usando o Tomcat 7
Códifo

linha com erro que eu não entendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo resoruce
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lib's

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Web.xml:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exception após rodar a aplicação
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No vavegador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você colocou as Lib's do Jersey dentro da pasta /WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: @adelmo00 sim, coloquei

Comment: Poderia postar o seu código, incluindo os imports?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares, um instante, vou enviar o código e os erro q retornam

Comment: O erro que está no Stacktrace é referente a falta da biblioteca que contém o Faces Servlet. Você pode encontrar para download aqui: https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma situação muito parecida com a sua no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration). Por essa resposta a solução está na versão do Java. O JDK 1.8 tem suporte a [métodos default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) nas interfaces o que implicou em novos métodos nas interfaces legadas (JDK 1.7 ou menor). A CharSequence é um caso...

Se seu projeto estive com nível de compatibilidade menor que 1.8, não podes referenciar esses default methods. Segundo a solução que citei (e acredito que ese é o caso), há duas opções:

1. Definir mesmo o JDK 1.7 como parte da sua solução e utilizar apenas libs compatíveis com o JDK1.7
2. Migrar definitiavamente para o JDK 1.8 (melhor opção na minha opinião).